# How to make get_header() call a custom header file located in a sub-folder of the theme?

Tags: wordpress, header

From a PHP template file located in a sub-folder of my WP theme folder (`my_theme/subfolder/my_file.php`) I want to use `get_header()` and call a custom `header-new.php` located in the same sub-folder.

Instead, `get_header(header-new)` loads `header.php` located in my theme root folder. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 21):

You are correct to use get_header() function. However, as per [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) you should pass the name of the custom header in the specific format - only the part that comes between 'header-' and '.php'. E.g. for the custom header in the file:

```
header-custom.php
```

you should use:

```
get_header('custom');
```

But that's not all. It is important to remember that the custom header file should be placed in 1 or 2 specific directories, depending on whether you're working on parent or child theme:

1. Parent theme: you should place it either in the same directory as the page template or the 'root' theme directory (specifically the same directory where your style.css is)
2. Child theme: you have to place it in the 'root' child theme directory

get_header() function calls [locate_template() function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/template.php#L0), which searches for the custom header file in those 2 directories. If it doesn't find the file, it defaults to 'header.php'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amade, this is the only trick that worked for me. But I believe the file that we moved to the root folder will just wipe away if we update the theme so how to handle that?

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal - do you work with a child theme? If so, then the updates of to the parent theme wouldn't affect you, as you're placing the header in the child theme's root.

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
get_template_part('header-new.php');
```

> reference here: >https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: actually, in this case, wouldn't it be 

get_template_part('new');

According to Wordpress*, "For the $name parameter, if the file is called "{slug}-special.php" then specify "special"."

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/